# 複数形はない日本語で、「質問・タグ・ユーザー」等のメニュをどうつたえる？

Tags: 討議, 翻訳, 日本語

このページがあります：

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

英語では複数形の言葉です：

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

問題は日本語では複数形がないため、「ユーザー」を見ると「自分のプロフィル」と勘違いする可能性があります。

このメニューをどう改善できますか？

例えば：

- 質問一覧
- タグ一覧
- ユーザー一覧
  （等）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「一覧」はつけずに

```
質問 | タグ | ユーザー | バッジ | 未回答
```

でよいと思います。複数形がないがゆえに、単に「質問」「タグ」という (一見「単数形」の) ラベルだけでも「この先には質問がいっぱいある」「こちらはタグに関するページ」という意味合いで使うことができます。

// 「ラベルだけ」でなく、「ページの上部にタブっぽい並びで単語が並んでいる」という文脈も効いていると思います。

> 「ユーザー」を「自分のプロフィール」と勘違いする可能性

こちらも文脈上、「グローバルな感じのナビゲーションバーに、自分だけのコンテンツがあるはずがない」という暗黙の了解から、勘違いされることはそうそうないのではないか、と思います。

Comment: 私もentoさんの案に賛成です。自分のプロフィールと勘違いする可能性はあまり無いと思います。
個人的に気になるのは「質問」とか「タグ」を選択して移動したページの表記が統一されていない点です。
「質問」->「すべての質問」、「タグ」->「タグ」、「ユーザー」->「ユーザー」、「バッジ」->「ヘルプ センター > バッジ」、「未回答」->「未回答の質問」という感じです。特に違和感があるのは「ヘルプ センター > バッジ」となっている所でしょうか。

Comment: @tomute, entoありがとうございます。翻訳を指示した通りに更新しました。今後のビルドで更新されます。